# .htaccess redirection not working on Apache/2.2.15

Tags: apache, perl, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The Apache version, I am using is 2.2.15.

My .htaccess looks like below :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myapp/

RewriteRule  ^service/name/(.+)$   /perlcode/cgi_script.pcgi?NAME=$1  [L]
```

As per the expected behavior, when I hit the short URL  for example,

```
myhost.com/myapp/service/name/delivery
```

in the browser, it should be converted to

```
myhost.com/myapp/perlcode/cgi_script.pcgi?NAME=delivery
```

However, I see that is not happening, instead the parameter is just getting appended to the short URL as below

```
myhost.com/myapp/service/name/delivery?NAME=delivery
```

I tried `[L,R=301]` and `[L,QSA,NC]` flags, but they are also converting the browser URL to the long one which I do not want. I want the URL conversion to take place silently behind the scene as it used to be in Apache/2.0.52

At the Perl code level (version 5.14.1), I see the `$cgi->self_url` is giving me this unexpected short URL with the parameter name appended  (i.e `myhost.com/myapp/service/name/delivery?NAME=delivery`).

Can anybody please help?

The Perl code looks like below :

```
 use CGI;

    my $cgi = CGI_>new();
    my $url = $cgi->self_url;
    my $service_name = $cgi->param('NAME');

    # In ideal case $url will hold 
    # myhost.com/myapp/perlcode/cgi_script.pcgi?NAME=delivery
    # then it substitutes the $url based on the $service_name and redirects
    if ($service_name eq 'delivery') {

        $url =~ s!/myapp/perlcode/cgi_script\.pcgi\NAME=$service_name!/myapp/percode/service!;
        $cgi->redirect($url);
    } elsif ($service_name eq 'order') {
         # does similar operation as above
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `[PT]` *passthrough* flag, which resubmits the modified URL to the mapping process

Without it the result is assumed to be a file path, in which context `?NAME=delivery`makes no sense

Comment: Hi Borodin, still no luck ! I used both [L,PT] and [PT] but did not notice any change. thanks.

Comment: How are you testing this? You talk about some Perl code. Please may we see what that is doing?

Comment: [***This***](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) may be useful, but I can't recommend it first-hand

Comment: Hi, I have added the Perl code editing my first post, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the CGI.pm version that is being used in my system. 
The version is 5.14.1 where some of the sub routines got changed than what
they were in earlier version (for example : 5.6.1).

Due to the change of sub routine sub url in CGI.pm, the output is coming like that which I do not want.

It is not a .htaccess problem, I think.

Thanks as always for your help.

Comment: The latest version of [CGI](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI) is 4.27. Where did you get v5.6.1 and v5.14.1 from? Also, I don't see how the module can have any effect on Apache's rewrite engine. However, if you have found a solution that works for you then very well done

Comment: Hi Borodin, I have added another answer for your query. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I mentioned the Perl version as 5.14.1.
The CGI.pm version which is giving me the unexpected output is 3.52 and the earlier CGI.pm version which is giving the expected output was 2.752.

Quite obviously, the CGI module has undergone several changes in between 2.752 and 3.52. Anybody interested, can have a look here http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.52/Changes